# Kekulé and his discovery of benzene

Tags: discoveries, chemistry, quote

> “I was sitting writing at my textbook, but the work did not progress; my thoughts were elsewhere. I turned my chair to the fire, and dozed. Again the atoms were gamboling before my eyes. This time the smaller groups kept modestly in the background. My mental eye, rendered more acute by repeated visions of this kind, could now distinguish larger structures of manifold conformations; long rows, sometimes more closely fitted together; all twisting and turning in snake like motion. But look! What was that? One of the snakes had seized hold of it’s own tail, and the form whirled mockingly before my eyes. As if by a flash of lightning I woke;.... I spent the rest of the night working out the consequences of the hypothesis. Let us learn to dream, gentlemen, and then perhaps we shall learn the truth but let us beware of making our dreams public before they have been approved by the waking mind.” -August Kekulé

---

This was the juncture when Kekulé discovered the structure of benzene. But what are the meanings of the metaphors he uses to describe?

1. "All twisting and turning in snake-like motion..."
2. "One of the snakes had seized hold of it's own tail..."
3. "The form whirled mockingly before my eyes..."

This question might look like it belongs to the English SE but it needs chemistry knowledge to answer it.

Can anyone please explain what Kekulé meant? It's evident that benzene is cyclic and unsaturated, but I feel he had subtle clues of benzene undergoing resonance and its other properties.

Comment: It is possible that what he wrote was just what he saw in his trance-like state. In such a state it is unlikely that he _meant_ anything.

Comment: No, I disagree on @mdewey's point. Some clue exists in this dream based on which he worked.

Comment: You know I didn't mean you should delete it on chem.se and post here? More like if you had questions like that in the future, hsm.se would likely appreciate them more.

Comment: So, to reiterate, he was making a connection between ouroboros and what we now call resonance.

Comment: Ohh I got confused.

Comment: See [Iurato, On Kekulé's insight](https://hal.science/hal-01584824) for a discussion of dream's meaning and the controversy surrounding it. Kekule gave several conflicting accounts of it, and the cyclic structure of benzene has been conjectured before him by Laurent, whose work he might have encountered. Some historians and chemists who studied his private papers even suggested that the "dream" was a made up tale to avoid sharing credit.